# Qt5/QML application doesn't use compositing anymore

Tags: xorg, qt, compositing

I am running a custom developed desktop environment on Kubuntu 17.04, which uses Qt5. I use QQuickWindows for UI elements. I still use X11 for now, but I'm keen to migrate to Wayland soon.

I use compton for compositing. Everything worked fine, but recently - after some system management I suspect - compositing is not applied to my program anymore, which means that all my windows have an opaque black background now.

I've already tried rolling back all the changes I made, resetting my compton configuration, even reinstalling it. The odd thing is that other programs use compositing just fine.

I do not use the Qt that's packaged for Ubuntu, but the cutting edge open source release. I'm almost certain that isn't related since it worked fine with the latest version (5.9.2) for a while.

Does anyone have any idea? I have a slight suspicion this is related to the removal of packages on my system.

Thanks in advance